# Am I trying to catch Feebas correctly?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I found the way to catch Feebas and changed the Trendy Phrase twice. After an attempt over 75 tiles, I just stopped it and went to sleep. The next day when I woke up, I found that the trendy phase had changed. Does that mean that Feebas's location has also changed and that I have to start over again? This has happened two days in a row.

Is there any way to prevent this or do I just have to do it only in one day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what (besides the player) influences a trendy phrase change, but; **yes**, [if the trend has changed, the 6 Feebas tiles were re-randomized](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hoenn_Route_119#Finding_Feebas), and might be among the 75 tiles you had previously checked under the previous trend.

Do keep in mind that a Feebas tile does not guarantee encountering a Feebas. So if you aren't already, you need to check every tile several times before moving on to the next.

Comment: The trendy phrase will only change if you a) Change it b) Make a change to the Trend and then don't save (thereby 'reverting' the change) or c) '[Record Mixing](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Record_mixing)' with another GBA's copy of RSE (In the 'Record Center' of any Pokemon Center)

Comment: @Robotnik The trendy Phase changes automatically after some time I guess. Actually what happened is When I submitted New trendy phrase all got rejected (All were same-:Abra Festival) and today I checked the trendy phase was changed to Abra Festival nevertheless it was rejected. BTW I got the feebass finally and just breeding to get proper nature